# Changing scene causes zoom

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

When going from GameScene to PlayScene using this code below, all works fine:

```
for touch: AnyObject in touches {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton1 {
                var scene = PlayScene(size: self.size)
                let skView = self.view as SKView!
                skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
                scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
                scene.size = skView.bounds.size
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
```

But when i am going from PlayScene to GameScene using this code below, it gets zoomed in:

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
            let skView = self.view as SKView!
            skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
            scene.size = skView.bounds.size
            skView.presentScene(scene)
        }
```

Tried to Updated code:

```
var scene = GameScene(size: self.size)
        let skView = self.view as SKView!
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

How come? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first code snippet, you create the new scene of `self.size` which keeps the same size as the old one. But in the second one, you use another method to do that, and the size of the new scene is initialized from the file **GameScene.sks** whose size is 1024x768 by default.

---

**EDIT:**

Did you use

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {...}
```

to create your first scene in your **GameViewController.swift**? If so, try to replace this line with

`let scene = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)`

I'm afraid the reason why your buttons get resized(zoomed) is that they are not in the right size at the first time you load **GameScene**, actually they are in a scene sized 1024x768. Your button is hard-coded as `400` width which is nearly the 1/3 of the scene width (1024pt). When you load **GameScene** again, its width now becomes the screen width, so you find buttons get resized. Print `scene.size.width` for more info.

Comment: One quick question more please, any idea why my buttons are transparent? Take a look at this: http://pastebin.com/7fHHmjqV

Comment: @Eri-Sklii add `background.zPosition = -1.0` to make your buttons in higher level than your background. The default `zPosition` of both is `0.0`, so your buttons becomes transparent which are covered by the `alpha=0.5` background.

Comment: Ah i forgot about the zPosition. Thank you very much for the help! :)

Comment: I have the same problem but i transition between scenes in a more simpler way , i go from Game Scene to StartMenu scene and on the start Menu everything zooms in and becomes larger any help please

my Game Scene TouchesBegane Function.
this is what i use to go to Start Menu Again
        if gamePlay == false {
            
            let scene = StartMenu(size: (view?.bounds.size)!)
            let skView = self.view!
            
            skView.presentScene(scene)
            self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
            
        }
any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
For me the problem was that the scene size had changed to be much smaller when going back to the first scene.

Scene 1) GameMap   Scene

- Original Scene Size: (1024.0, 4096.0)
- Original View Size : ( 320.0,  480.0)

Scene 2) GameLevel Scene

- Original Scene Size: ( 320.0,  480.0)
- Original View Size : ( 320.0,  480.0)

When Moving from Scene 1 to Scene 2 everything looked fine but when moving back from Scene 2 to Scene 1 The "Scene 1" size is changed to Scene 2's size

Scene 1) GameMap Scene  -> After Going Back

- Original Scene Size: ( 320.0,  480.0)
- Original View Size : ( 320.0,  480.0)

My solution was to specifically change the size of the scene in "didMoveToView" and set the scaleMode of the "Scene 1" see below:

```
    self.view?.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, Constants.screenWidth, Constants.screenHeight)
    self.scene?.size = CGSizeMake(1024, 4096)

    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill
```

Hope it helps
BR
BuD