# (SpriteKit Objective-C) Scene Stretched Out After Transition

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, transition, scene, stretch

When I transition from `MainMenuScene.m` to `SceneLvl1.m`, the transition works perfectly fine. But when transitioning back from `SceneLvl1.m` to `MainMenuScene.m`, all the sprites are distorted. They're stretched out to almost **3x** their original width! Here's my transitioning code:

```
// Main Menu initialization.
    MainMenuScene *mainMenu = [[MainMenuScene alloc] init];


// Move to the main menu.
[self.scene.view presentScene:mainMenu
                       transition:[SKTransition fadeWithColor:[SKColor blackColor]
                                                     duration:3.0]];
```

So, what could I be doing wrong, here?

Comment: similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31930786/changing-scene-causes-zoom

Comment: @WangYudong That didn't work for me. Two things: **1**, that's in Swift, anyway. But I know swift, so it's fine. **2**, the solution is something I did at the beginning of the project, so it isn't relative.

Answer (score 1):

This might sound a stupid question, but are you calling simply init in it?
Any scene initialization should use initWithSize, right?
Try replacing with

```
    MainMenuScene *mainMenu = [[MainMenuScene alloc] initWithSize:self.view.frame.size];
```

Comment: This is my guess as to what's happening as well.  It's likely a scene sizing issue.  Also check the scaleMode property of the scene - that determines things like whether it stretches the view or letterboxes it or resizes it to fill.